# Scatter plot from csv file doesn't get the right value

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to scatter data with this code:

```
  GNU nano 2.5.3                           File: scatter                                                    Modified  

#!/usr/bin/python3
import pandas
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import numpy as np
D = pandas.read_csv(sys.stdin, sep=",", header=None, index_col=0)
D.plot(kind="scatter", rot=30, legend=False)
plt.title("Mijn scatter")
plt.show()
plt.savefig("Mijn_scatter.pdf")
exit(0)
```

the data is in the form of:

```
5432.3,0.3421
8654.23,0.5643
etc
```

but it keeps giving the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scatter", line 9, in <module>
    D.plot(kind="scatter", rot=30, legend=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 3671, in __call__
    sort_columns=sort_columns, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 2556, in plot_frame
    **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 2342, in _plot
    kind=kind, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 1525, in __init__
    super(ScatterPlot, self).__init__(data, x, y, s=s, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 1499, in __init__
    raise ValueError(self._kind + ' requires and x and y column')
ValueError: scatter requires and x and y column
```

and I think the error keeps appearing because I don't assign a value to x or y anywhere, but I dont know where or how.

the pipeline i have to get the data:

```
cat | bzcat /vol/share/groups/liacs/scratch/pt2020/Open_Data_RDW__Gekentekende_voertuigen-sample.csv.bz2 | 
grep Personenauto | 
awk -F "," '{print $3 "," $24 "," $51}' | 
awk -F "," '{a[$1]+=$2} {b[$1]+=$3} {c[$1]++} END {for (i in c) {if(c[i]>10) print i "," a[i]/c[i] "," b[i]/c[i]}}'|
awk -F "," '{print $2"," $3}'|
python3 scatter
```

the original data is a big list of cars and info about that car

Comment: If you pipe the output to a file instead of as stdin to your python script, does reading the csv directly replicate the issue?

Comment: @C.Nivs Yeah, I still get the same issue if I first output it to a file, I got a tip from a classmate that I need to put both colomns in an numpy array.

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what’s wrong. Scatter requires you to specify the `x=` and `y=` arguments where those are the column labels for the respective columns.

Comment: Yes but how do I do that @ALollz

Comment: What are the column names? (If you don’t know, `print(D.columns)`). You’d then reference them just as you specify the kind or rot arguments

Answer (score 0):

While using pd.read_csv, set `index_col=None` or **remove index_col** parameter

According to your current code, index_col sets the first column as the index of dataframe. Hence, you only have the second column, which gets you only x column.

Current dataframe (`index_col = 0`):

| Index | Column |
| --- | --- |
| 5432.3 | 0.3421 |
| 8654.23 | 0.5643 |
| ... | ... |

Using (`index_col = None`) or not mentioning index_col at all:

| Index | Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5432.3 | 0.3421 |
| 1 | 8654.23 | 0.5643 |
| ... | ... | ... |

This should probably work, Here's the [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) of the pandas documentation if you want to check it out.
**Finally**,

```
D.plot(x=0, y=1, kind="scatter", rot=30, legend=False)
```

According to [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), x and y specify the column position in the dataframe.